# SQL multicolumn index

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Is there a way to index a `table A (id int pk, columnA int, columnB int)` for following query:

```
select * from A where columnA > columnB
```

Currently I added `columnC = columnA - columnB` and changed query to:

`select * from A where columnC > 0` (with index on columnC)

Comment: What DBMS are you using? This is tagged as MySQL and SQL Server :/

Comment: Currently I'm using mysql but I would like to know answer for both of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set indexes on columnA and columnB and simply do

```
select * from A where columnA > columnB
```

and let the sql engine do the work; I don't think there's a fastest way without make complicated things like adding a new column as you've done: in this way you have to remember to update everytime you change a value in one of the two columns and can lead to errors

Comment: Did you mean a separate index on both of the columns or index(columnA, columnB) ?

Comment: yes I mean a separate index on every column, I don't think using an aggregate index on the two columns may be useful time-wise for your query...it may even slow it down

Comment: If the answer satisfies your question may you mark this as answered?
Thank you.